# NoMethodError for plus sign in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

I am really new at `ruby`. I have created a function to count occurrences of words in a string. However, I am getting `NoMethodError` for `+` all the time. I searched, tried different variations, but couldn't solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
def count_words(str)
    str_down = str.downcase
    arr = str_down.scan(/([\w]+)/).flatten
    hash = Hash[]
    arr.each {|x| hash[x] += 1 }
    (hash.sort_by {|key, value| value}.reverse)
end
```

Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from ./***.rb:14:in `count_words'
    from ./***.rb:14:in `each'
    from ./***.rb:14:in `count_words'
    from (irb):137
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
hash = Hash[]
arr.each {|x| hash[x] += 1 }
```

To

```
hash = {}
arr.each {|x| hash[x] =0 unless hash[x]; hash[x] += 1 }
```

OR

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
arr.each {|x| hash[x] += 1 }
```

EXPLAINATION

```
hash = {}
hash[1] = "example1" #ASSIGNMENT gives hash = {1: "example1"}
p hash[2] #This gives `nil` by default, as key is not present in hash
```

To give default value to the key which is not present in hash we have to do the following:

```
   hash = Hash.new("new value")
   p hash #Gives {}
   p hash[4] #gives "new value"
```

Comment: `hash[x] = 1` for the first occurrence?

Comment: The problem for my attempt is to increase the value of `hash[x]`, but there is no value there when the first item iterates. Right?

Comment: Yes tht's right, you can set that default value, `0` in your case using `hash = Hash.new(0)`

Comment: How about the situation when we have string instead of integer for hash values? It is `hash = Hash.new('')`, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In the first iteration, h[x] is nil. Trying to add 1 to nil throws error. Setting the initial value of h[x] to 0 will solve the issue.

```
arr.each {|x| hash[x]||=0; hash[x] += 1 }
```

instead of

```
arr.each {|x| hash[x] += 1 }
```